# Regex - pattern for allowing only numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get a REGEX which allows only number starts from 1-9 and only of 4 characters and should can only have a zero after decimal.

This is what i have written so far, but it fails every time.

```
^[1-9]\\d{4,4}(\\.\\d{1,1})?%?$
```

I am using this as a validation in java while reading an excel sheet.

Comment: for eg: 2016.0 - Pass

Comment: I have tried this as well "^([1-9]\\d{4}.\\d{1})*$"

Comment: here's a helpful link - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: You can use this regex: `^[1-9]\\d{3}(?:\\.0)?$`

Comment: @Anubhava - Thanks it works. I as missing the : in between.

Answer (score 1):

For your given requirements you may use this regex:

```
final String regex = "^[1-9]\\d{3}(?:\\.0)?$";
```

**RegEx Breakup**

- `^`: Start
- `[1-9]`: Match a digit `1-9` at start
- `\\d{3}`: Match any 3 digits
- `(?:\\.0)?`: Match  **optional** `.0` at the end
- `$`: End

Comment: Just to know, why did you choose to do `[1-9]\\d{3}` and not `\\d{4}` ? Is there a difference ?

Comment: Because `\\d{4}` will also allow `0` at the start but `[1-9]\\d{3}` won't.

Comment: Ah right, did not see that 0 was not a starting number

Comment: @Anubhava. Yes it did. Thanks.